# how to validate hidden form field name which is not present in HTML form using servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have two HTML forms one has the Hidden Field tag and another doesn't have the tag. When validating the First HTML Form which has Hidden Field tag, I can validate in servlet by getting the field name and value of it. example as shown below,

**HTML Form With Hidden Tag**

```
<form action="/myServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<input type="hidden" name="myname" value="myvalue"/>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

**Servlet validating Hidden Field**

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iter;
iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   item = iter.next();
   String fileName =  item.getName();
   String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
   if (item.isFormField()) {
   String fieldValue = Streams.asString(item.openStream());
   if (fieldName.equals("myname")){ //validating Hidden form tag name
         // some process goes here
   }
}
```

With the above code i can validate the Hidden Form field, but if i have an HTML form as below which doesn't have a Hidden tag then how to process my servlet for validation.

**HTML Form Without Hidden Tag**

```
<form action="/myServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
//No hidden tag
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

I'd like to be able to validate these different cases:

1. Form with hidden field, and some content in the request for the field: VALID
2. Form with *empty* hidden field: INVALID
3. Form without hidden field: VALID

The main problem is differentiating between the two last cases.

Comment: what have you tried , did you tried executing it and see , yes the hidden field can be accessed in the servlet by name , have you tried checking it ??

Comment: @Sabarish What do you mean by validating in this case? If you don't have the myname field you can't validate it. I assume it's another name for the uploaded file. If you don't have myname you could assign the fileName attribute.

Comment: yes i can access the servlet when hidden tag is present, my question is, as i know the name of hidden tag i can validate in servlet. If hidden tag is not present in HTML then in what way i can validate in the servlet.

Comment: You can't because it won't be ever send to your servlet. Why do you expect that your browser (or other client) send to your server value of field which doesn't exist?

Comment: @onepotato i have to different HTML form one with Hidden tag and another without hidden tag. If hidden tag is present the with the above servlet i can validate whether it has value or not. In other case if i don't have the tag itself how come i can validate in servlet. Hope you understand

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? You cant access something that does not exist.

Comment: @stacker I mean that validating here is whether i have field name and value or not.

Comment: I think I understand what the OP wants: to differentiate between 1, the form having an EMPTY hidden form tag (invalid case!), and 2, not having the hidden field at all (this would be considered valid!).

Comment: @ppeterka Exactly.. Thats what my question

Comment: I edited your question to be a bit more clear, and reflect the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to know whether the myname attribute is present, you could set a flag indicating that. Or store the value in a String which is initialzed with null.

```
    boolean hasMyName = false;

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
       item = iter.next();
       String fileName =  item.getName();
       String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
       if (item.isFormField()) {
          String fieldValue = Streams.asString(item.openStream());
          if (fieldName.equals("myname")){ //validating Hidden form tag name
             hasMyName = true;
          }
    }

    if ( hasMyName ) {
        // myname is present, do something
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this but you can give this a try:

1. Make a hidden field in your form in the case where you think it should exist say field name is "myHiddenField".
2. Now, try to see is there any difference b/w value of this field when you try to get it when:

a. It is not present.

b. It is blank.

Try to see if there if you are able to get some distinction like null and blank value. As I said, I haven't tried it myself. I can be wrong here in my assumption.